# No videos in the mostPopular chart for certain video categories

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get a list of the most popular videos for certain video categories, however some categories return an empty list of videos despite the response being successful.

For example, the News & Politics category (ID 25):

[image: Example request]

I get the same response when making this request from my app. The category ID is valid and correct (as obtained from `/youtube/v3/videoCategories`). Changing the `regionCode` doesn't make a difference.

---

It's really important for the functionality of my app that a list of popular/recent/noteworthy videos for particular categories are shown. If there's no way to get the above request to return some videos, **is there some kind of workaround** that would return appropriate videos for the troublesome categories?

Comment: Which method exactly are you calling as far as i can see video categories doesnt take those parameters.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list

Comment: @DaImTo `/youtube/v3/videos?chart=mostPopular&videoCategoryId=25&regionCode=US&part=snippet`

Comment: yes but what method is that in the actual API? where did you get that url?  it looks almost like videos list https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Comment: @DaImTo Exactly, it's the "list" method on the "Videos" endpoint, the one you linked. Why "looks **almost** like videos list", what looks wrong to you?

Comment: @DaImTo Out of interest, if you go to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list, choose the "`list (most popular videos)`" use case radio button, enter `25` as the `videoCategoryId` param, and hit execute, do you get the same success response with an empty `items` array as I am seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me

I tested it in the [apis-explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=us&videoCategoryId=25&_h=4&)

**Testing request 1:**

Without category.  [test here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=50&regionCode=us&fields=items%252Fsnippet%252FcategoryId&_h=10&)  scroll down there are some with nr 25

**Request**

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=50&regionCode=us&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2FcategoryId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

**Response**

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/ewwRz0VbTYpp2EGbOkvZ5M_1mbo\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 50
 },
 "items": [
     "snippet": {
     "categoryId": "25"
      }
  ......
 ]
}
```

but as soon as you add the catagori id it returns 0

**Test 2 fun results**

A fun thing i found in my testing is if i add a category id of 10 [link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=50&regionCode=us&videoCategoryId=10&fields=items%252Fsnippet%252FcategoryId&_h=12&)

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=50&regionCode=us&videoCategoryId=10&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2FcategoryId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

it returns others as well.

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "categoryId": "24"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "categoryId": "10"
   }
  },
  {
   "snippet": {
    "categoryId": "10"
   }
```

I would submit a bug report. [issue forum](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B)

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful to have you verify that behaviour. And thanks for the link to the issue tracker. Is it good or bad Google API etiquette to bump an issue by duplicating... worryingly, there is an issue for this bug posted over 2 years ago! (https://issuetracker.google.com/35177397) Since it doesn't look likely to be fixed any time soon, would you have any insights as to a workaround to get a reasonable list of videos for that category to show in an app?

Comment: I can try to find someone at google to ping about it but i have never had much luck getting YouTube API issues fixed.   I would rip out as many as you can by region and sort the category id locally.

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but don't go out of your way to reach out to somebody if it would feel like flogging a dead horse. I'll pull in tonnes of non-category-specific popular videos and filter down to those from the relevant category, as you suggest. Thanks again

Comment: Just to add here that the popular videos chart doesn't seem to return more than a total of 200 videos (across all pages of results). For the News & Politics category, it's only returning 3 videos right now – not great.

Comment: TBH I didn't know YouTube had anything to do with real news so I am not all that surprised